# Exclusive-NOR (XNOR) and his CNF sub-expression

Tags: logic

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation), for example, we have the AND gate and its CNF sub-expression:

$(\neg A \lor \neg B \lor C) \wedge (A \lor \neg C) \wedge (B \lor \neg C)$

What is the CNF sub-expression for the Exclusive-NOR (XNOR) logic gate?

Comment: Isn't the CNF form of the AND gate just $A \wedge B$?

Comment: @Glorfindel: It is a CNF form of $C\leftrightarrow (A\land B)$, which is useful when constructing a CNF that is satisfiable iff a given Boolean network is, without risking an explosion in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read a CNF off the truth table for XNOR: $C \leftrightarrow \overline{A\oplus B}$ exactly iff
$$ A \land B \to C \\
A \land \bar B \to \bar C \\
\bar A \land B \to \bar C \\
\bar A \land \bar B \to C $$
which by unfolding the implications becomes
$$ (\bar A \lor \bar B \lor C) \land \\
(\bar A \lor B \lor \bar C) \land \\
(A \lor \bar B \lor \bar C) \land \\
(A \lor B \lor C) $$

Comment: Thank you very much for help!

Comment: It should not be in the formula: $ ... \wedge (A \lor B \lor C)$?

Comment: @MarekWolny: That last was a typo, of course. Now fixed,